# Python CGI error trying to execute a sqlite command

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm not sure why it says that the table ajax_exmaple does not exist... I check sqlite3 to see that the database and the tables along w/ their corresponding datas are all there. Any ideas?

When I try to execute this command:

```
query_result = c.execute(query, (sex, age, wpm))
```

...I get:

```
<class 'sqlite3.OperationalError'>: no such table: ajax_example 
  args = ('no such table: ajax_example',) 
  message = 'no such table: ajax_example'
```

This is my complete code:

```
#!C:\python27\python.exe
import cgi, cgitb, sqlite3
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-type: text/html"
print ""

conn = sqlite3.connect('../htdocs/ajax_ex.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Capture URL query
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
age = form.getvalue('age')
sex = form.getvalue('sex')
wpm = form.getvalue('wpm')

# Build SQL
query = "SELECT * FROM ajax_example WHERE ae_sex = ?"
if(isinstance(age, int)):
query += " AND ae_age <= ?"
if(isinstance(wpm, int)):
query += " AND ae_wpm <= ?"

# Execute query
query_result = c.execute(query, (sex, age, wpm))
conn.close()

# Build result string
display_string = '''
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Sex</th>
    <th>WPM</th>
</tr>'''

# Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
for row in query_result:
display_string += "<tr>"
display_string += "<td>row['ae_name']</td>"
display_string += "<td>row['ae_age']</td>"
display_string += "<td>row['ae_sex']</td>"
display_string += "<td>row['ae_wpm']</td>"
display_string += "</tr>"

print "Query: ", query, "<br>"
display_string += "</table>"
print display_string
```

Comment: What is the complete path of the database file? What is the current directory when you are running this script?

Comment: html file at c:/apache24/htdocs  which calls the python script at c:/apache24/cgi-bin/script.py  i've tried using the whole path and flipping the backslash w/ forward slash with no luck.

Comment: What are the permissions on C:\apache24\htdocs and its parent directories? What user is the script run as?

Comment: All files involved (htdocs, cgi-bin, script.py, .html, ajax_ex.db (sqlite3 db) have read, write, execute permissions. I'm not sure about what user runs the script. I visit localhost and from the .html page, I call the script.

Comment: Windows does not use `rwx` permission bits. Too see which user Apache runs as, check Service Manager.

Comment: @CL. It's run as me, the user, with full control... I thought I got it working, but I guess not.